# ODBC - Connecting to a server with two databases with the same name

Tags: odbc, progress-db

I'm trying to connect to two databases using an ODBC into a Progress Database - the catch is that they both have the same name on the same server. I don't think I can change the database name, so is it possible to have an ODBC connection for both databases, or do I need to move it to a different server?

Thanks

Comment: Please, elaborate a little more your question and show us what you tried so far to solve your problem.  Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The port number (-S parameter) makes the connection unique.